# How to not use decorators while using connect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am new to react & redux and hence came across a decorator implementation and now figuring out on how to mold into as per my requirements.
Following is the syntax I came through, which i need to convert to non-decorator form:

```
@connect(
    state => ({
        authentication: state.authentication
    }),
    dispatch => bindActionCreators(LoginActions, dispatch)
)
```

and the form to which i need to convert is:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    authentication: state.authentication
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    authenticateUser: (email, password) => dispatch(loginUser(email, password))
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the non-decorator form of your syntex. you can even use the "Fat Arrow" functions to make it simple

```
  function mapStateToProps(state, prop){
    return {
      authentication: state.authentication
    }
  }

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
      action: bindActionCreators(LoginActions, dispatch)
    }
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, one of the way solve your problem is below(you can use short notation for mapDispatchToProps)

```
export default connect( state => {
   authentication: state.authentication
}, { loginUser })(LoginContainer);
```